# Incorrect gripper joint visualisation for Franka Panda

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the Moveit Setup assistant to generate the inertial tags and manually adding the transmission tags to get a URDF for the Franka Panda to be used in ROS Sharp. ROS Sharp like gazebo requires the inertial and transmission tags to work and Franka ROS doesnt provide such a urdf or xacro which is why I used Moveit setup assistant to generate it.

When using it, the gripper's fingers (prismatic joints) move weirdly although the arm's revolute joints move perfect. I am not sure if this is an issue with the autogenerated URDF from the moveit setup assistant? To inquire if it is an issue with ROS Sharp I have posted an issue for it [there](https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/176).

Here is the [urdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N9QAvoCjonv4m2fsWhjEnsK78c3SAzGJ/view) generated with MoveIt plus the transmission tags I have added. Also [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11A8gqhVw5bwIcVgSBlAOjKjBHF5oTNhh/view) is an image showing the weird gripper positions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317963/incorrect-gripper-joint-visualisation-for-franka-panda/) by [akcast](https://answers.ros.org/users/38544/akcast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2019-03-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-08**:
Please attach images to your questions directly. If your google drive account or the files ever get deleted, this question loses quite a bit of its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Closing this as it has been solved in ROS Sharp [Issue #176](https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues/176)

---

Originally posted by [akcast](https://answers.ros.org/users/38544/akcast/) with karma: 46 on 2019-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0